# Can you use any Java library with an android app?

Tags: java, android, modbus

For example, if I wanted to use EasyModbusJava with my android app, would it be as simple as adding the jar file as a library dependency or are there certain restrictions on libraries?

Comment: Be aware that if you want to use a library which requires a certain Java version (such as Java 8) then you will need to configure your Android project to require a minimum Android platform version which permits Java 8, which will mean you make your app incompatible with handsets running earlier versions of Android. (Also note that [Android still supports only a subset of Java 8 features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html).)